# last_scored_timestamp, last_scraped_timestamp

Tags: apache-2.2

What does last_scored_timestamp and last_scraped_timestamp mean in apache error log?

google and bing returned no usable results

example from log

> [Mon Jul 30 11:15:07 2012] [error] [client 216.52.89.82] File does not exist: /var/www/site/page.php|last_scored_timestamp:1343664987|last_scraped_timestamp:1343664986

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's part of the URI.  It's not a special field in the Apache error log.

Since there's no referrer, it's not obvious where the client got the URL from.  I suspect it's a badly written client and you will find other weirdness in the same request's line from the access log.

It could also be a normal bot combined with a badly written website that contains a link to this incorrect URL or an email that contained the incorrect URL that a normal user has clicked on.

The parameters themselves make me suspect the badly written bot.